# How do I drag a file onto Chrome? (Mac OSX Lion)

Tags: osx-lion

I have a file on the desktop that I want to drag onto a window (my browser).
Suppose the browser is fully maximized.

How can I do that in Lion?

Before, in Snow Leopard, I could swipe up (reveal desktop), click + drag the file, then swipe down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Finder, click and hold on an file icon, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to Chrome and release the icon. The same technique should work even if Chrome is running in Lion-esque fullscreen mode, and if you are dragging something from the desktop.

If you're having troubles getting to the actual desktop, I do know that the Show Desktop gesture in Lion has changed. You may need to activate/configure it in System Preferences -> Trackpad -> More Gestures, so now "Spread a thumb and three fingers" to view the desktop.

[image]

Comment: That takes too long. I want to go directly to the desktop, and then back to the application.